# How to display a table onclick submit if textbox is not null demo: https://jsfiddle.net/21bbc4wm/

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display a table on click submit only if text box is not null

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/21bbc4wm/

When i click submit button it returns no table, pls can someone help me out of this

```
    <input type="text" list="user" id="note" name="Username"
       placeholder="User ID*" autocomplete="off" required />

    <div id= "container1" style="display:none;">
    <p style="text-align:center; font-size:160%;">Search Result</p>


    <table id="demo">
              <tr><th>User ID</th>
              <th>Date</th><tr>
    </table>

 <td><button style="background-color: #4CAF50;" id = "buttonSubmit" 
 type="submit" value="Submit" onclick ='check(); return 
false'>Submit</button></td>
```

Javascript:

```
function check()
{
if(document.getElementById("note").value == null || 
document.getElementById("note").value == "")

  {
  alert("You must mention User ID for the result!!!");
  document.getElementById("note").focus();
  return false

  var x = document.getElementById("container1");
if (x.style.display = "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "true";
}
}
```

Comment: Post the code that you've tried so far (including your HTML and a precise explanation of what you're looking for) if you want help, else this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: fix your question because we can't see the code

Comment: Pls comment now you should see the code

Comment: @iltech show me the button.do you warp it with form tag?

Comment: @לבנימלכה here:  <td><button style="background-color: #4CAF50;" id = "buttonSubmit" 
 type="submit" value="Submit" onclick ='check(); return 
false'>Submit</button></td>

Comment: pls help if anyone can

Comment: @iltech <div id= "container1"  do you close this tag? why do u insert the button inside td

Comment: *Please*, indent your code and use one [indenting style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) consistently throughout your code. Doing so makes it **much** easier to read/maintain. As a side effect, doing so for code you place on Stack Overflow makes it much more likely that you will get people to up-vote your posts and makes it more likely that people will put time into Answering your Questions. It doesn't matter which style your choose (although, IMO, some are more appropriate for JavaScript than others). But, pick one and use it consistently for all code in a single project.

Comment: @לבנימלכה please follow the link to understand my requirement https://jsfiddle.net/21bbc4wm/

Comment: Please do whatever changes is necessary for my requirement to the code and I ll be thankful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
 var table = document.getElementById("demo");
  var content = document.getElementById("container1");
  var val = document.getElementById("note");
  
 if(e.target.id === "buttonSubmit") {
   if(val.value === null || val.value === "") {
     alert("You must mention User ID for the result!!!");
      content.classList.remove("active");
      val.focus();
    } 
    else {
     var date = new Date();
     /* remove this line for stacking */ table.innerHTML = '<tr><th>User ID</th><th>Date</th><tr>';
      table.innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + val.value + '</th><td>'+ date.toDateString() +'</th><tr>';
      val.value = "";
      content.classList.remove("active");
      content.classList.add("active");
   }
  }
  if(e.target.id === "buttonReset") {
      table.innerHTML = '<tr><th>User ID</th><th>Date</th><tr>';
      val.value = "";
      content.classList.remove("active");
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  font-size: 1em;
}
#container1 {
  display: none;
}
#container1.active {
  display: block;
}
#result {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 160%;
}
#buttonSubmit {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#buttonReset {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" list="user" id="note" name="Username"
       placeholder="User ID*" autocomplete="off" required>

<div id="container1">
  <p id="result">Search Result</p>
  <table id="demo">
    <tr><th>User ID</th>
      <th>Date</th><tr>
  </table>
</div>
<a id="buttonSubmit">Submit</a>
<a id="buttonReset">Reset</a>
```